# Heroku Deploy of Java app fails using Ant Buildpack

Tags: java, heroku, ant

I'm trying to deploy the following app to Heroku:
https://github.com/raeffu/ch.bfh.bti7081.s2015.Blue/

I'm using the [Ant Buildpack](https://github.com/dennisg/heroku-buildpack-ant).

After executing

```
$ git push heroku master
```

the build is successful and then this error message appears at the end of the log:

```
remote:        BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[.....]
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote:
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 236.4MB
remote: -----> Launching... failed
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failure creating release
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to healvis.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/healvis.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/healvis.git'
```

The Procfile looks like this:

```
web: java -jar lib/webapp-runner-8.0.18.0-M1.jar --expand-war --port $PORT target/healvis.war
```

The log does not reveal any helpful information.

How can I find out more what's going wrong or, even better, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the addon `shared-database` required by the buildpack.

I forked the repository and removed the addon, now it works.